# How can I call teo columns from a tablar function in a SQL Server stored procedure at a same time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[PaymentStatusProviderDetailView]
    (@POId INT ,
     @ProviderId INT ,
     @PrrId INT)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        SDID,
        dbo.GetServiceDetailString(SDID) AS ServiceName,
        POID,
        AmountPaid, AmountHeld,
        ProviderName,
        (SELECT ReimbursementAmount
         FROM dbo.GetReimbursementBilledAmounts(@POId, SDID, @ProviderId, @PrrId)) AS ReimbursementAmount, 
        (SELECT ServiceMonth
         FROM dbo.GetReimbursementBilledAmounts(@POId, SDID, @ProviderId, @PrrId)) AS ServiceMonth
    FROM    
        (SELECT    
             SD.Id AS SDID, PO.Id AS POID,
             SUM(PD.PaymentAmount) AS AmountPaid,
             PH.HoldAmount AS AmountHeld,
             PROV.ContractorName AS ProviderName
         FROM      
             [dbo].[PaymentDetail] PD
         JOIN 
             PurchaseOrder PO ON PO.Id = PD.PO_Id
         JOIN 
             fBusinessUnit BU ON BU.id = PD.BU_Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             Reimbursement_EBSUtilization REU ON REU.Id = PD.REU_Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             Reimbursement_CDSUtilization RCU ON RCU.Id = PD.RCU_Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             PaymentHold PH ON PH.PO_Id = PO.Id
                            AND (PH.RCU_Id = PD.RCU_Id OR PH.REU_Id = PD.REU_Id)
         LEFT JOIN 
             ProviderReimbursementRequest PRR ON (PRR.Id = REU.PRR_Id OR PRR.Id = RCU.PRR_Id)
         LEFT JOIN 
             fContractor PROV ON PROV.Id = PRR.Contractor_Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             CDSUtilization CDS ON CDS.Id = RCU.CDSU_Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             fServiceDetail SD ON SD.Id = REU.SD_Id OR SD.Id = CDS.ServiceDetail_Id
         WHERE     
             Po.Id = @POId
             AND PRR.Contractor_Id = @ProviderId
             AND PRR.Id = @PrrId
         GROUP BY  
             SD.Id, PO.Id, PH.HoldAmount, PROV.ContractorName

         UNION

         SELECT    
             SD.Id AS SDID, PO.Id AS POID,
             NULL,
             SUM(PH.HoldAmount) AS AmountHeld,
             PROV.ContractorName AS ProviderName
         FROM      
             PurchaseOrder PO
         JOIN 
             PaymentHold PH ON PH.PO_Id = PO.Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             Reimbursement_EBSUtilization REU ON REU.Id = PH.REU_Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             Reimbursement_CDSUtilization RCU ON RCU.Id = PH.RCU_Id
         LEFT JOIN 
             CDSUtilization CDS ON CDS.Id = RCU.CDSU_Id
         JOIN 
             ProviderReimbursementRequest PRR ON PRR.Id = REU.PRR_Id OR RCU.PRR_Id = PRR.Id
         JOIN 
             fContractor PROV ON PROV.Id = PRR.Contractor_Id
         JOIN 
             fServiceDetail SD ON SD.Id = REU.SD_Id OR SD.Id = CDS.ServiceDetail_Id
         WHERE     
             Po.Id = @POId
             AND PRR.Contractor_Id = @ProviderId
             AND PRR.Id = @PrrId
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM PaymentDetail PD
                             WHERE PH.PO_Id = PD.PO_Id
                               AND (PH.RCU_Id = PD.RCU_Id OR PH.REU_Id = PD.REU_Id))
         GROUP BY  
             SD.Id, PO.Id, PROV.ContractorName) DT
    END
```

In the above stored procedure, in the particular code I am calling the same tablar function twice for two columns

```
 (SELECT ReimbursementAmount
  FROM dbo.GetReimbursementBilledAmounts(@POId, SDID, @ProviderId, @PrrId)) AS ReimbursementAmount,
 (SELECT ServiceMonth
  FROM dbo.GetReimbursementBilledAmounts(@POId, SDID, @ProviderId, @PrrId)) AS ServiceMonth
```

How can I call the above function in the same stored procedure only once and obtain two column names at the same time?

Say for example like below

```
 (SELECT ReimbursementAmount, ServiceMonth
  FROM dbo.GetReimbursementBilledAmounts(@POId, SDID, @ProviderId, @PrrId)) AS ReimbursementAmount and ServiceMonth
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Short answer: you **cannot** do that. A subquery in a `SELECT` statement cannot return more than one value.

Comment: I thought you could use `CROSS APPLY` in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks like a limitation in sql server . we should only use a column function to retrieve or display a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
SELECT .......
........
RI.ReimbursementAmount,
RI.ServiceMonth,
...

FROM
.....
....
CROSS APPLY dbo.GetReimbursementBilledAmounts(@POId, SDID, @ProviderId, @PrrId) RI
     WHERE     
     Po.Id = @POId
     AND PRR.Contractor_Id = @ProviderId
     AND PRR.Id = @PrrId
....
..
```

Comment: IT does work but the issue is still i should call the same function twice in both queries in union statements.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying